# How to group particular fields from the list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting lists from service. But In that particular service i need only 2 fields values alone. I write a select query, but it is not returning all lists.

```
var TranslResult = serviceResponse.Result.ToList();

selectedReasons = TranslResult.Select(x => new TranslationContentEntity
{
    ContentId= x.ContentId,
    ContentType= x.ContentType
});
```

But i am getting result of the following,
[image]

Comment: So, you need return only `ContentId` and `ContentType`? You can try to use anonymous classes for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use anonymous class like this :

```
selectedReasons = TranslResult.Select(x => new 
{
     ContentId= x.ContentId,
     ContentType= x.ContentType
});
```